# Plotting level curves in MATLAB for a complex function

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I am trying to plot the contour plots for the given function

```
syms r x y k z
[ph,r] = meshgrid((0:5:360)*pi/180,0:.5:10);
[X,Y] = pol2cart(ph,r);
Z = X+i*Y;
J = besselj(k,l.*r);
J2 = besselj(k,m.*r);
Y = bessely(k,l.*r);
Y2 = bessely(k,m.*r);
H = besselh(k,r);
F1 = symsum((J).*exp(1i*k*ph),k,-5,5);
F2 = symsum((J2+Y2).*exp(1i.*k.*ph),k,-5,5);
F3 = symsum(H.*exp(1i.*k.*ph),k,-5,5);
pwu = nan(size(F1), 'like', F1);
mask = 0 <= r & r < 0.5;
pwu(mask) = F1(mask);
mask = 0.5 <= r & r < 1;
pwu(mask) = F2(mask);
mask = r >= 1;
pwu(mask) = F3(mask);
U = subs(pwu, {l, m}, {1.5, 3});hold on
contour(X,Y,imag(double(U)),30)
axis equal
xlabel('r','FontSize',14);
ylabel('phi','FontSize',14);
```

but I keep getting errors for the form of the 4th last line. Apparently  U cannot be converted to a double. Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what is `l`? please post a [mcve]

Comment: Your code has multiple problems. The variables (syms) l, m, are no initialized. Though you initialize you will get error in the contour; this is because Y is a symbolic variable.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
syms r x y k z
[ph,r] = meshgrid((0:5:360)*pi/180,0:.5:10);
[x,y] = pol2cart(ph,r);
Z = x+1i*y;
J = besselj(k,l.*r);
J2 = besselj(k,m.*r);
Y = bessely(k,l.*r);
Y2 = bessely(k,m.*r);
H = besselh(k,r);
F1 = symsum((J).*exp(1i*k*ph),k,-5,5);
F2 = symsum((J2+Y2).*exp(1i.*k.*ph),k,-5,5);
F3 = symsum(H.*exp(1i.*k.*ph),k,-5,5);
pwu = nan(size(F1), 'like', F1);
mask = 0 <= r & r < 0.5;
pwu(mask) = F1(mask);
mask = 0.5 <= r & r < 1;
pwu(mask) = F2(mask);
mask = r >= 1;
pwu(mask) = F3(mask);
U = subs(pwu, {l, m}, {1.5, 3});hold on
J0 = besselj(k,r);
u0 = symsum(1i.^(-k).*J0.*exp(1i*k*ph),k,-5,5);
W = U+u0;
contour(x, y, angle(double(W)), 30);
axis equal
xlabel('r','FontSize',14);
ylabel('phi','FontSize',14);
```

Thanks for your comments!